# Grid - auto columns up to nn max number without knowing children size

Tags: css

I'm trying come up with a way to have a grid-like container with *`nn`* maximum number of columns but it would wrap into fewer columns if needed to fit into width of the screen.

One of the issues is the children's sizes are unknown and second issue, there is a sticky pseudo element in the container which also would have to be resizes to spawn across entire row.

In the following example it set to have max of 4 columns, but when container resized it doesn't wrap into fewer columns. (also note, the resizable container is just to emulate screen size, in reality it will be the size of its content)

```css
.box
{
  --cols: 4;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--cols), 1fr);
  min-width: min-content;
  min-height: 4em;
  overflow: auto;
  resize: both;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.box::before
{
  content: "sticky element";
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: calc(var(--cols) + 1);
  height: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
.box > *
{
  max-width: 3em;
  max-height: 3em;
  min-width: 3em;
  min-height: 3em;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

It doesn't have to be grid, as long as there is a way have max number of columns without altering html structure.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

**As you asked for any tips**, I created a *Flexbox Layout* solution that does what you want, but can not meet all your requirements (for now). Being just 'a tip', we could discuss the below and make it work as required.

**intermediate solution**

With a flexbox parent container (demo `.grid`) you can use the `column-gap` value to force row content to wrap to the next line:

- Resize item *column gap* relative to the current parent *client width* and number of *columns* required, divided by the number of *columns*.

Essentially taking the current parent width, subtract the total width of the maximum number of required child columns and distribute the remaining space between those columns. The *Flexbox mechanism* will handle the wrapping taking CSS parent and child property values into account. *The catch* is that the column width needs to be known to get a total column width to subtract from the parent width. *(And I understand you don't know, Hence, 'tip'!)*

- Equation:  `columngap = (clientWidth - columnWidth * columns) / columns`
- CSS: `column-gap: max(0px, calc( (var(--clientWidth) * 1px - var(--colSize) * var(--cols)) / var(--cols)))`. Clamped to `0px` with `max(..)` to prevent creation of negative space.

By lack of proper *CSS grid* knowledge I could not get the above to work with your original code. *Flexbox Layout* seems to work as I expected.

- The Javascript includes a simple `ResizeObserver` which, on `.grid` resize, passes the current `grid.clientWidth` to *CSS custom variable* `--clientWidth` to be used in above CSS calculation. *(Unused `clientHeight` only there for completeness.)*

*Fun observation: the CSS grid mechanism seems to use a similar calculation in certain cases, as the orginal `.box CSS grid` spacing is equal to the proposed `.grid flexbox calc(..)`.*

When you run the snippet, go 'Full page', try the range sliders and resizing the browser first as using the 'resize-handle' will break the regular browser window resize effect.

**snippet**

BTW with 'console' enabled, the snippet shows a Javascript error only on Stackoverflow. Elsewhere it seems to be none existent...

```js
/* Reference to parent grid elements involved */
const grids = document.querySelectorAll(".grid");

// Set variables to initial values per grid
window.onload = function () { grids.forEach((grid) => { setVariables(grid) }) };

// Create a resize observer to set variables with changed grid size
const ro = new ResizeObserver(list => {
  for (let entry of list) { setVariables(entry.target); }
});
// But only observe .grid(s)
grids.forEach((element) => { ro.observe(element) });

// Set custom variables to current size to enable use in CSS
function setVariables(grid) {
    grid.style.setProperty("--clientWidth" , grid.clientWidth );
    grid.style.setProperty("--clientHeight", grid.clientHeight); // here for completeness
};
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box }

body {
    --cols   : 4;
    --colSize: 3em;
}

.grid {
    position: relative; /**/

    resize: both; overflow: auto;

    display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap;

    /* Flexbox child alignment, enable/change/fiddle what fits best */
/*    justify-content: start; /* Main axis */
/*    align-content  : start; /* Cross axis */
/*    align-items    : center; /* perpendicular to Main axis, when applicable */
 
    column-gap: max(0px, calc( (var(--clientWidth) * 1px - var(--colSize) * var(--cols)) / var(--cols)));
    /* Change to 'gap' for equal horizontal AND vertical speading */
    
    width: 100%; /* stretch to fill parent width */

    min-height: 4em;
    border: 1px solid;

}
.grid::before {
    content: "sticky element (solution .grid)";
    position: sticky;

    /* Shorthand for T/R/B/L; Over content */
    inset: 0 0 auto 0; z-index: 1;

    width: 100%; /* required, despite inset and z-index. Huh? */
    /* Even parent `position: relative` has no effect. */
    /* 'flex-basis: 100%' instead would work too */
    
    height: 1.5em; /* 'min-height' maybe? For when line breaks? */

    background-color: lightblue;
    text-align: center;
}
.grid > * {
    width : var(--colSize); /* Use range slider value */
    height: var(--colSize);

    border: 1px solid;
    background-color: pink;
}

/* This and thats for the demo */
input[type="range"] { width: 100% }
label, input        { display: block; font-size: 1em }
label,li            { margin-bottom: 0.5rem }


/*******************************************
    Original code with modded '.box > *'
    using the '--colSize' variable for
    comparison purposes.

    Also: moved '--cols' to 'body' above.
*******************************************/
.box {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--cols), 1fr);
    min-width: min-content;
    min-height: 4em;
    overflow: auto;
    resize: both;
    border: 1px solid;
}
.box::before {
    content: "sticky element (original .box)";
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: lightblue;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: calc(var(--cols) + 1);
    height: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
.box > * {
    max-width : var(--colSize);
    max-height: var(--colSize);
    min-width : var(--colSize);
    min-height: var(--colSize);

    border: 1px solid;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<label><b>columns</b>&nbsp;-&nbsp;[1 - 9] <span id="info-cols"></span>
        <input type="range" min="1" max="9" step="1" value="4"
               oninput="document.body.style.setProperty('--cols', this.value);
                        document.getElementById('info-cols').innerHTML = ' > ' + this.value;">
    </label>

    <label><b>column size</b>&nbsp;-&nbsp;[1 - 15em] <span id="info-size"> &gt; 3em</span>
        <input type="range" min="1" max="15" step="0.25" value="3"
               oninput="document.body.style.setProperty('--colSize', this.value + 'em');
                        document.getElementById('info-size').innerHTML = ' > ' + this.value + 'em';">
    </label>

<br>
<div class="box">
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="grid">
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```